# json_encode from php array: how do I adjust my php so my array is correct?

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, coffeescript

I am trying to create a php array from posted values and then json_encode to achieve this:

```
[{"network_type":"facebook","network_url":"fb.com/name"},{"network_type":"twitter","network_url":"@name"},{"network_type":"instagram","network_url":"#name"}]
```

which after json_decode looks like:

```
array(
 [0] => stdClass(

 network_type = 'facebook'
 network_url = 'fb.com/name'
 )

 [1] => stdClass(

 network_type = 'twitter'
 network_url = '@name'
 )

 [2] => stdClass(

 network_type = 'instagram'
 network_url = '#name'
 )
)
```

My php looks like this:

```
$social_data = array(

          'network_type'    => $this->input->post('network_type'),
          'network_url'     => $this->input->post('network_url')
    );
```

and so the array is not grouped the way I want it, but rather by the field name:

```
array(
['network_type'] => array(
  [0] => 'facebook'
  [1] => 'twitter'
  [2] => 'instagram'
)
['network_url'] => array(
  [0] => 'fb.com/name'
  [1] => '@name'
  [2] => '#name'
)
```

and therefore the result of the json_encode isn't grouped how I want it:

```
 {"network_type":["facebook","twitter","instagram"],"network_url":["fb.com/name","@name","#name"]}
```

)

So the question is...how do I adjust my php so the array is correct?

--- here's the input fields:

```
<?php
        foreach ($social as $key => $value) {?>
         <p>
              <label for="network_type"><input type="text" size="20" name="network_type[]" value="<?php echo $value -> network_type; ?>" placeholder="Social Network" /></label>
              <label for="network_url"><input type="text" size="20" name="network_url[]" value="<?php echo $value -> network_url; ?>" placeholder="URL or Handle" /></label>
              <a class="remNetwork" href="#">Remove</a>
          </p>
      <?php } ?>
```

----latest update:  this is sooooo close!-----
Ok, for some reason (probably me botching things one way or another), both suggested methods below didn't quite get me there....but, a mix of both methods has gotten me close:

This if/loop/array setup:

```
 $network_type    = (array)$this->input->post('network_type', true);
$network_url     = (array)$this->input->post('network_url', true);
$social_data = array();


if (($counter = count($network_type)) == count($network_url)){
for($i = 0;$i < $counter; $i++) {
    $social_data[$i] = array(
            'network_type'    => $this->input->post('network_type[$i]'),
            'network_url'     => $this->input->post('network_url[$i]'),
        );
  }
}
```

paired with this input loop:

```
<?php
        foreach ($social as $key => $value) {
      ?>
         <p>
              <label for="network_type"><input type="text" size="20" name="network_type[]" value="<?php echo $value -> network_type; ?>" placeholder="Social Network" /></label>
              <label for="network_url"><input type="text" size="20" name="network_url[]" value="<?php echo $value -> network_url; ?>" placeholder="URL or Handle" /></label>
              <a class="remNetwork" href="#">Remove</a>
          </p>
      <?php } ?>
```

is yielding the following:

```
array(
  [0] =>  array(
    ['network_type'] => FALSE
    ['network_url'] => FALSE
  )
  [1] => array(
    ['network_type'] => FALSE
    ['network_url'] => FALSE
  )
  [2] => array(
    ['network_type'] => FALSE
    ['network_url'] => FALSE
  )
)
```

So, I think if I can figure out why these values are false, then we've done it!
Thanks and appreciation for your patience and help in advance...

-- update again ----
To my dismay, I've left out a piece that's perhaps critical...the coffee script that's dynamically creating the form fields when there's more than one social:

```
$ ->


socialDiv = $("#social")
  i = $("#social p").size() + 1
  index = 0
  $("#addNetwork").click ->
$("<p><label for=\"network_type[]\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"network_type[]\" size=\"20\" name=\"network_type[]\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"Social Network\" /></label><label for=\"network_url[]\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"network_url[]\" size=\"20\" name=\"network_url[]\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"URL or Handle\" /></label> <a href=\"#\" class=\"remNetwork\">Remove</a></p>").appendTo socialDiv
i++
false
$(document).on "click", ".remNetwork", ->
      #$(".remNetwork").bind "click", ->
        if i > 1
          $(this).parent("p").remove()
          i--
        false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, i can asume that `network_type` and `network_url` are inputs like:
`<input type="text" name="network_type[]" />` and `<input type="text" name="network_url[]" />`

so in order to accomplish what you want you would:

```
<?php
$networkType = (array)$this->input->post('network_type', true);
$networkUrl = (array)$this->input->post('network_url', true);

$networkData = array();
if (($counter = count($networkType)) == count($networkUrl)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; ++$i) {
        $networkData[] = array(
            'network_type' => $networkType[$i],
            'network_url' => $networkUrl[$i]
        );
    }
}
?>
```

and should give you the desired json.
However, this approach is a bit clunky and unreliable.

Instead, i would define the input fields like:

`<input type="text" name="network[0][network_type]" />` and `<input type="text" name="network[0][network_url]" />`

`<input type="text" name="network[1][network_type]" />` and   `<input type="text" name="network[1][network_url]" />`

and i would generate the php array like:

```
<?php
$networkData = (array)$this->input->post('network', true);
?>
```

Just my two cents :)

L.E:
To make it detailed and create the std objects from your array, you would:

```
$networkData = array();
if (($counter = count($networkType)) == count($networkUrl)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; ++$i) {
        $obj = new StdClass();
        $obj->network_type = $networkType[$i];
        $obj->network_url = $networkUrl[$i];
        $networkData[] = $obj;
    }
}
print_r($networkData);
```

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a shot...I just updated my post so you can see the context of the input fields

Comment: added coffee script piece that might help

Comment: Posted the files below in comments to Deryck

Comment: my answer is correct, the only difference is that it returns an array of arrays instead of an array of StdClass objects, which you can create in the for loop like: `$obj = new StdClass(); $obj->network_type  = $networkType[$i]; $obj->network_url = $networkUrl[$i]; $networkData[] = $obj`

Comment: yep that did it :) ... I still had to do a string replace to remove the brackets around the class so the POST would only be in curly braces, allowing me to decode and populate the form fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through as you feed them into the `$social_data` array.  It would be

```
for($i = 0;$i < $items.length;$i++) {
    $social_data[$i] = array(
            'network_type'    => $this->input->post('network_type[$i]'),
            'network_url'     => $this->input->post('network_url[$i]'),
        );
```

The resulting array will look like:

```
$social_data[0] -> 
    'network_type' => 'facebook',
    'network_url' => 'fbook.com/user'
$social_data[1] ->
     ...etc
```

I'm not totally sure what context you're getting the `network_type` and url but they will both be arrays and looping through for each individual value is what to do.  Without the rest of the code it's hard to get much more specific but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a shot...I just updated my post so you can see the context of the input fields

Comment: added coffee script piece that might help

Comment: Sorry there's just not enough code for me to go off of.  The original problem wasn't limited to coffee but I'm guessing the functions and variables I don't recognize probably come from there.  If I get the full script I'll take another look though.

Comment: Here's the files to view.  coffee:http://cl.ly/code/0T08012v290a controller:http://cl.ly/code/3A3g0E3F3o3l  view:http://cl.ly/code/3y242I0L2k1J

Comment: I noticed that if I look at the firelog of $social_networks I see double square brackets wrapping my json array: [[{"network_type":"Facebook","network_url":"fb.com\/user"},{"network_type":"Twitter","network_url":"@user"}]]

which breaks my code when repopulating the form; whereas manually deleting one set of the brackets (in the sql field seems to resolve things:   [{"network_type":"Facebook","network_url":"fb.com\/user"},{"network_type":"Twitter","network_url":"@user"}]

Comment: and to clarify (lol...if possible), the removal of the set of square brackets is really the removal of the only outside set of square brackets in the sql field, so there's only curly braces wrapping the json data in the field (apparently two sets in firelog = one set in the json)